# How can transfer data from the point domain to the face corner domain

Tags: geometry-nodes, interpolation

I could use some help with transfering data between domains.

I want a value stored in the point domain and value coming from the edge domain interpolate to the face corner domain,so I can adjust the face corners with that value.
As the vertex is linked to multiple face corners, I want to use a value from the edge domain to adjust the right face corner.

For example 2 edges that are connected at an angle. They share the same vertex. I want to be able to move the face corner of its vertex and belonging to an edge move in the tangent direction of the edge.

Therefore I also need to know how I can transfer data from the edge domain to the point domain.

I guess the nodes of `vertex of corner`, `corners of vertex`, `vertices of edge` and `edges of vertex` come in handy, but I just don't understand how they seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Greetings,
M3D

Comment: i think a small sketch would really improve your question so that it is clear what you want to achieve